# Disabling Samsung Calendar on Galaxy S4 mini

Tags: applications, samsung, calendar

I'm trying to disable my Samsung calendar so that I don't get two notifications of events on my Galaxy S4 mini.
In settings I don't seem to have any options to change application settings.

Comment: I think the name of Samsung's Calendar app is "S-Planner" in app list. Find it and you can follow steps in below mentioned answer...

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is,

> Goto -> Settings -> Apps/Application manager -> Find Calendar

and then do `Show Notification` to Disable or tap for disable.

and also after find the Calendar in `Apps`, you can disable it or Clear cache or anything you want.

hope this helps.